# C union type in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, unions

How can I declare and use a C union type in Swift?

I tried:

```
var value: union {
      var output: CLongLong
      var input: [CInt]
    }
```

but it does not work...

UPDATED: I want to use union to split a `8 bytes number` to 2 x `4 bytes number`.

Comment: There is no direct support of unions in Swift, but you can use enumeration to accomplish your requirement.

Comment: Unions are disfavoured by just about every C and C++ coding standard know to man because they are so frequently used to write non-portable code.  If you have a choice in the matter, never use a `union` in C, and in all cases unpack whatever data is contained within with bit-wise operators.

Comment: @marko,  I would have to disagree with your premise.   For instance, when receiving a message, where the message can have any of several different formats, it is almost always implemented as a union of those formats, typically where the first, non header, field indicates which message type is contained in the rest of the message, where the rest of the message is defined as the union of all the message types.

Comment: This is *precisely* the scenario which I was thinking of. by using an union here we're trying to overlay the a storage layout onto a stream of bytes - for instance, received from the network, or another process.  The portability hazards are myriad because of alignment, structure packing and endianness varying from one architecture to another.

Comment: @user3629249 There are better options to handle such situations. In OOP languages you would use inheritance, every message type represented by a different class, in C you can use pseudo-inheritance.

Comment: A data type containing bit fields isn't inherently unsafe, but it's implementation at least the way C does using union is. In Ada, you can declare types sized in bits and compose them into a larger type while preventing unsafe operations on them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the Apple Swift document , [Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) can do similar thing and more.

> Alternatively, `enumeration` members can specify associated values of
>   any type to be stored along with each different member value, much as
>   `unions` or `variants` do in other languages. You can define a common set
>   of related members as part of one enumeration, each of which has a
>   different set of values of appropriate types associated with it.

1) If you just want to split a 8 bytes number to 2 x 4 bytes numbers, as you might have known, the [Bitwise Operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) of Swift could help. Just like

```
let bigNum: UInt64 = 0x000000700000008 //
let rightNum = (bigNum & 0xFFFFFFFF) // output 8
let leftNum = (bigNum >> 32)  // output 7
```

2) If you want to simulate the `union` behaviour like `C` language,
I tried a way like this. Although it works, it looks terrible.

```
enum Number {
    case a(Int)
    case b(Double)

    var a:Int{
        switch(self)
        {
        case .a(let intval): return intval
        case .b(let doubleValue): return Int(doubleValue)
        }
    }

    var b:Double{
        switch(self)
        {
        case .a(let intval): return Double(intval)
        case .b(let doubleValue): return doubleValue
        }
    }
}
let num = Number.b(5.078)

println(num.a)  // output 5
println(num.b)  // output 5.078
```

Comment: (2) is not like a C union at all, it's just converting between double and int. A C union would have both vars share the same memory location, so storing the 8 bytes Double(5.078) takes up and reading them back as an Int would not return 5, but 0x40144FDF3B645A1D (4,617,403,338,154,334,749, yikes!)

Comment: Semantically, it IS similar to union. Unions mean sharing a spot in memory. A swift enum does this, except that it adds on a byte for the enum value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no direct support of unions, in Swift, but we can use enumeration for our purpose.

Ex-

```
enum Algebra {
  case Addition(Double, Double)
  case Substraction(Double, Double)
  case Square(Double)

  var result : Double {
    switch(self)
    {
    case .Addition(let a, let b): return a + b
    case .Substraction(let a, let b):  return a - b
    case .Square(let a):  return a * a
    }
  }
}

let solution = Algebra.Addition(5, 3)
println(solution.result) //Output: 8.0
```

Comment: Seems to be not the same purpose, I want split a `8 bytes number` to 2 x `4 bytes numbers`

Comment: That's an unsafe operation which is intentionally not supported in Swift. Now obviously what you want to do is trivial to achieve with shift and bitwise and operations. A Swift enumeration will _never_ let you re-interpret data in a different way. Fully intentional.

Answer (score 3):

Swift discourages "unsafe" programming patterns like `union`, however, there is a workaround. It's a bit ugly, but here goes (using Xcode 7.2)...

```
struct VariantA {
    var oneField: Int // 8 bytes

    struct VariantB {
        var firstField: UInt32 // first 4 bytes
        var secondField: UInt32 // second 4 bytes
    }

    var variantB: UnsafeMutablePointer<VariantB>  {
        mutating get {
            func addressOf<U>(something:UnsafePointer<U>)
                -> UnsafeMutablePointer<VariantB> {
                return UnsafeMutablePointer<VariantB>(something)
            }
            return addressOf(&oneField)
        }
    }
}
```

Now a quick check of `sizeof(VariantA)` will show the whole structure still takes up only eight bytes (which is one 64-bit integer). If we now create an instance like this `var a = VariantA(oneField: 1234567890987654321)` then we can query the components like this `a.oneField` which will return the initial value 1,234,567,890,987,654,321 and also `a.variantB.memory.firstField` will return 2,976,652,465 and `a.variantB.memory.secondField` will return 287,445,236.

We can change one of the components like this `a.variantB.memory.firstField++` and then observe that this changes the original value of `a.oneField` to 1,234,567,890,987,654,32**2** as expected.

The ugly parts for me are the occurrences of the words "unsafe", "pointer" and `.memory.` as well as that `addressOf` helper function which is only there to overcome a compiler error in Xcode 7.2!

Perhaps working with lower-level structures that require byte-level manipulation like this should not be done in a high level language like Swift at all. Have you considered writing this part of your project in a .c file? With a suitable bridging header you can still do the majority of your project in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Here I define `MyUnion` which has two member named `f` and `g`. As you see, `union` is unsafe, and `enum` with associated value is preferred, though it's a bit different from `union`.

```
// Simulate union of the C programming language
// f and g share memory
struct MyUnion {
    fileprivate var ivar: UInt32 = 0 // Shared memory, private is better.

    var f: Float {
        get { return Float.init(bitPattern: ivar) }
        set { ivar = newValue.bitPattern }
    }
    init(f: Float) { self.f = f }

    var g: Int32 {
        get { return Int32(bitPattern: ivar) }
        set { ivar = UInt32(bitPattern: newValue) }
    }
    init(g: Int32) { self.g = g }
}

var u = MyUnion(f: 13.12)
u.f    // 13.12
u.g    // 1095887749
u.ivar // 1095887749

u.f = -99.123
u.f    // -99.123
u.g    // -1027195142
u.ivar // 3267772154

u = MyUnion(g: -1)
u.f    // nan
u.g    // -1
u.ivar // 4294967295
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can make a C union in a struct in ObjC code, and when imported in swift it will behave like it's supposed to. Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_structs_and_unions_in_swift

"Swift imports C unions as Swift structures. Although Swift doesn’t support natively declared unions, a C union imported as a Swift structure still behaves like a C union."

Answer (score 0):

Your union doesn't specify the type of the structure, so I would assume you are always deriving that from the context (you always know if the value is either `output` or `input`). In that case, I would translate it into two separate structs:

```
struct OutputValue {
    ...
}

struct InputValue {
    ...
}
```

If you want the structs to have some common properties/methods, declare a `protocol` for it.