# Trying to convert union in C to Swift

Tags: c, swift, xcode, structure, unions

How do we change following code in Swift?:

```
typedef union
{
    uint32_t raw;
    struct
    {
        uint32_t type : 2;
        uint32_t offset : 16;
        uint32_t count : 12;
        uint32_t baseaddrse : 2;
    };
} header_t;
```

Comment: We try to do it ourselves first.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962399/c-union-type-in-swift)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force translation.  The property `raw` holds the value, and the computed properties `type`, `offset`, `count`, and `baseaddrse` read and write the sub fields.

The utility functions `readbits()` and `writebits()` take care of packing and unpacking the values.

All of the ugliness is hidden in the structure itself.  Using it is straightforward, just as in C.  You can set a `raw` value, and then read out the individual fields, or you can set the values of the fields and then read out the `raw` value.

```
struct Header_T {
    var raw: UInt32 = 0
    
    func readbits(start: Int, end: Int ) -> UInt32 {
        let nbits = start - end + 1
        let mask = UInt32.max >> (32 - nbits)
        return (raw >> end) & mask
    }
    
    mutating func writebits(value: UInt32, start: Int, end: Int) {
        let nbits = start - end + 1
        let mask = UInt32.max >> (32 - nbits)
        let imask = UInt32.max ^ (mask << end)
        raw = (raw & imask) | ((value & mask) << end)
    }
    
    var type: UInt32 {
        get { readbits(start: 31, end: 30) }
        set(newType) { writebits(value: newType, start: 31, end: 30) }
    }
    
    var offset: UInt32 {
        get { readbits(start: 29, end: 14) }
        set(newOffset) { writebits(value: newOffset, start: 29, end: 14) }
    }
                                
    var count: UInt32 {
        get { readbits(start: 13, end: 2) }
        set(newCount) { writebits(value: newCount, start: 13, end: 2) }
    }
    
    var baseaddrse: UInt32 {
        get { readbits(start: 1, end: 0) }
        set(newAddr) { writebits(value: newAddr, start: 1, end: 0) }
    }
}
```

---

### Tests

```
var foo = Header_T()
foo.type = 3
foo.offset = 0
foo.count = 4095
foo.baseaddrse = 0

print(String(foo.raw, radix: 2))
```

> ```
> 11000000000000000011111111111100
> ```

```
foo.type = 2
foo.offset = 65535
foo.count = 0
foo.baseaddrse = 3

print(String(foo.raw, radix: 2))
```

> ```
>  10111111111111111100000000000011
> ```

```
foo.raw = 0b11_1111111111111110_111111111110_01
// Expect 3, 65534, 4094, 1
print(foo.type)
print(foo.offset)
print(foo.count)
print(foo.baseaddrse)
```

> ```
> 3
> 65534
> 4094
> 1
> ```

Comment: How did that work for you? Questions? Comments?